# Should I synchronize on the current object instance or on the data structure instance?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some code as follows:

```
class MyClass {

private Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

public void checkAndAddToSet(Integer i) {
  if (!set.contains(i)) {
    set.add(i);
  }

public void checkAndRemove(Integer i) {
  if (set.contains(i)) {
    set.remove(i);
  }
}
}
```

I need the code to be thread-safe so I have two options, I can either `synchronize` on the current instance of this class, i.e. `synchronized(this)` or I can synchronize on the `Set` instance, i.e. `synchronized(set)`.

Which is the better choice here? I am leaning towards synchonizing on the data structure object `set`, but only because in the future I may need to do further synchronization in the class but use different object locks.

Comment: I think guarding against the `set` should suffice. Also, consider making the `set` final. Do you need to call `contains()`? The contract of the `Set` interface (satisfied by `HashSet`) already checks that and _returns_ boolean values to convey to caller what it did.

Comment: so, have you found any answer?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which monitor lock you choose as long as you are not planning to choose this lock at another code elsewhere.

Even though if I have to choose between the two, I would prefer `synchronized(this)` over `synchronized(set)`. The reason for that is because I need to check the Hashset code that whether it is using any `synchronizied(this)` for any synchronization internally. 
So I can safely use `synchronized(this)` to my code peacefully.

Answer (score -1):

If you have other synchronized methods that don't depend of that Set instance you can use `synchronized(set)`, otherwise there is no problem using `synchronized(this)`. But I recommend use [Collections.synchronizedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedSet(java.util.Set)) at all, independent if you have another synchronized methods as well.

like

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
Set safeSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(set);
```

Comment: Using `Collections.synchronizedSet(set)` won't make the `set` thread safe against the operations in question. We would still need client side locking to achieve the same.

Comment: @Tirath i think it's only necessary to sync when use iterator over the set... Please explain why don't apply to this question

Comment: Agree with the sync over iterator. Lets say we have the `safeSet` and we use it inside the `checkAndAddToSet` and `checkAndRemove` methods in question. These methods aren't synchronized and thats a problem. Lets assume we modify to make then synchronized. Now, these methods acquire the monitor of `MyClass` instance not of `safeSet`. We have two different locks. I think this proves my point.

Comment: @Tirath `"These methods aren't synchronized and thats a problem."`. How can be this a problem if `safe.add()` and `remove()` are synchronized by the wrapper given from `Collections.synchronizedSet(set)`. Please explain how `checkAndAddToSet` can be broke in a multithread environment

Answer (score -2):

It depends.

When you say `synchronize(this)` or you add `synchronize` key word to your method declaration - it actually synchronizes on the `MyClass` instance which is used to invoke this method.

But, if you synchronize on the hand coded `Set` instance - it will acquire the monitor associated with this instance and use that for synchronization.

As your code stands, you should be fine with both the approaches whereas if you are planning to use `MyClass` as a utility class - to carry out `putIfAbsent` functionality then you should sync on `Set` instance.